# What happened to my KDE task bar? How can I get it back?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, kde

I installed a 32bit Kubuntu on my Netbook (Aspire One 150) and the first logon after the installation was just fine. However, after applying some upgrades, turning off the effects etc, I have some kind of "launcher" with the task bar (or something like it) at the top, a button named "Menu" at the top left and when I click that button I get a "Close" menu entry, but clicking that yields no result whatsoever? There are something like tabs in that launcher, the first named "Search and launch", the second "Page one".

How can I get the usual KDE desktop back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you somehow got the KDE "netbook" interface, assuming it looks like this:
http://www.kde.org/workspaces/plasmanetbook/

You can switch the workspace under System Settings -> Workspace -> workspace type; set it to "desktop".  Here's a screenshot:
http://paste.opensuse.org/80239345